# How to migrate an app in flutter from android 12 to android 13?

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart

I need to migrate my application from android 12 to android 13 since in android 12 it does not show any errors, however when testing the app on a device with android 13 it gives me the following error:

> [MethodChannelFilePicker] Platform exception:
> PlatformException(read_external_storage_denied, User did not allow
> reading external storage, null, null).

I've tried adding validations in the manifest, like the ones in:

I have also tried adding these validations in the main:

Answer (score 0):

Add the following permission in your manifest.xml inside

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MEDIA_CONTENT_CONTROL"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

If it still does not work out, upgrade or change the package you use for picking files and check the documentation.

recommended : https://pub.dev/packages/file_picker/versions/5.2.5

Comment: Hi @bibek saha,

I fixed the problem by updating this:

minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 32

Answer (score 0):

Referring to:
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/13/behavior-changes-13
[image]

You might want to request the individual Images/Video/Audio permissions if android 13+ is detected.